# apostrophe error

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and MySQL as main languages while TinyMCE for the WYSIWYG feature. The problem is I get a MySQL error everytime I try to place an apostophe on the text editor. the error appears to be like this:

> An error occured upon executing query.
>   Please notify the web developer about this error.
>
> NOTE: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 's definitely a program for you.
>
> International Language Academy Manila (' at line 1

The statement leads me to this set of code:

```
function ExecuteQuery($strquery){
  $rs = mysql_query("$strquery") or 
        die('<br><br>An error occured upon executing query.<br>Please notify the web developer about this error.<br><br>NOTE: '.mysql_error());
  return $rs;
}
```

But i can't seem to understand the problem. Need some help here. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please post the query you tried.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: How could we help you to find the syntax error without the query???

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659879/mysql-php-with-special-characters-like-apostrophe-and-quotation-mark?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing error because an apostrophe has special meaning in Mysql. As Ian said you have to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on `$strquery`

Not using escaping will lead to serious SQL injection security issues. http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

```
function ExecuteQuery( $strquery ) {
  $rs = mysql_query(mysql_real_escape_string($strquery)) or 
        die('<br><br>An error occured upon executing query.<br>Please notify the web developer about this error.<br><br>NOTE: '.mysql_error());
  return $rs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that your query is something like this...

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('blah blah blah');
```

Now, imagine what will happen when the text you're trying to insert contains single quotation marks/apostrophes...

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('This won't work.');
```

Any single quotes in the content of the query parameters are breaking your code. You need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on your query parameters.

Better yet, use PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (textfield) VALUES ( 'your editor value' );
```

Now, you probably do not escape your input value, so an apostrophe in your text would break the query

```
INSERT INTO table (textfield) VALUES ( 'your ' editor value with apostrophe' );
```

[Read this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to learn about escaping, also have a close look at the red box