# getting query error for special characters ie " ' " tag

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

> Query Error : CALL spCheckUserMailAccount('way2waymail@gmail.com',
>   '2', 'D'cruz', 'way2waymail@gmail.com') Details: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'cruz',
>   'way2waymail@gmail.com')' at line 1
>
> Query Error : CALL spAddMailAccount('way2waymail@gmail.com', '2',
>   'D'cruz', 'way2waymail@gmail.com', '123456', 'smtp.gmail.com', '465')
>   Details: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'cruz', 'way2waymail@gmail.com', '123456', 'smtp.gmail.com',
>   '465')' at line 1

Comment: The apostrophe is a special SQL character used to encapsulate text content. If you have data requiring apostrophes, your front-end application ought to handle that for you. One way would be by using escape characters. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659879/mysql-php-with-special-characters-like-apostrophe-and-quotation-mark

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating values with double quotes. Some thing like CALL spCheckUserMailAccount("way2waymail@gmail.com", "2", "D'cruz", "way2waymail@gmail.com"). If you still get errors, try using mysql_real_escape_string.
Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Whenever inserting fields into a db always check for single quotes. If you have already inserted them then I believe you will have to use the REPLACE function to retrieve the proper value

```
SELECT REPLACE(Customer_Name, '\'', '') FROM table
```